# PHP date difference

Tags: php

I have two dates in string formate i want to calculate these things from the two date strings.
1) Year difference
For example

```
$date1 = "20/04/2002";
$date2= "20/04/2010";
$five_yers_back = <Five years back that is 2005>
```

similarly

```
$date2= "20/05/2010";
$a_week = "< seven days back from date2 >";
```

Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strtotime + date

```
http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's classes to do this for you. But as a C programmer I prefer the basics of a tm structre. PHP equivalent example here

```
<?php

$d1 = "20/04/2002";
$d1rec = strptime( $d1, "%d/%m/%Y" );
$sec = 0;
$min = 0;
$hour = 0;
$day = $d1rec["tm_mday"];
$mon = $d1rec["tm_mon"] + 1;  # Because tm_mon is 0-11
$year = $d1rec["tm_year"];
print( "DATE: " . strftime( "%d/%m/%Y\n"
              , mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$mon,$day,$year) ) );
print( "+1WK: " . strftime( "%d/%m/%Y\n"
              , mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$mon,$day+7,$year) ) );
print( "+2WK: " . strftime( "%d/%m/%Y\n"
              , mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$mon,$day+14,$year) ) );
print( "+1YR: " . strftime( "%d/%m/%Y\n"
              , mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$mon,$day,$year+1) ) );
print( "-6MO: " . strftime( "%d/%m/%Y\n"
              , mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$mon-6,$day,$year) ) );

?>
```

So basically

- Use `strptime` to parse your string into a structure array
- Break the array into variables
- Use `mktime` to recombine the (modified) variables into a time_t integer (and take care of month/year wrapping)
- Use `strftime` to get back to a string